# Checking answer here to confirm if it's question mistake or mine: $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\tan (x - x)}{\sin (x-x)}$ = indetermined? why wrong?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, derivatives

I encountered a questions with asking to evaluate: $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\tan (x - x)}{\sin (x-x)}$, and gives multiple choice options $-2, 0, 1, 2$ but doesn't have indetermined...

If I used trig identities, I'd get $\frac{1}{\cos (x-x)}$ by converting tan to $\frac {\sin}{\cos}$ so the best guess is 1, but that's still wrong.

Please can someone tell me where my gap is? I'm learning l'Hopital rule if that helps, but even applying that gives $\frac{0}{0} = \text{indetermined}.$ Could the question be wrong..?

Comment: You are calculating the limit of an indeterminate term. The numerator and denominator are not tending to zero, they are $\textbf{equal to  zero}$ for all real $x$. Moreover, $\frac{\tan 0}{\sin 0} \neq \frac1{\cos 0}$.

Comment: $\tan(x-x)/\sin(x-x) = \tan(0)/\sin(0)$. It would be constant, and undefined everywhere. The expression is invalid.

Comment: @AmanKushwaha , the answer below seem to get $\frac{1}{cos(x-x)}$ as well. To get there it's $\frac{sin(x-x)}{cos{x-x}}$ (From tan(x-x)) $* \frac{1}{sin(x-x)} = \frac{1}{cos(−)}$

Comment: Is the best choice in this case 0?

Comment: How do we get to 0..? whatever tends towards 0 minus the same should be 0, so it's $\frac{\tan 0}{\sin 0}$, which even if we solve for directly... answer is.. $\frac{0}{0}$ which makes it indeterminate?

Comment: @nvs0000 $\frac{\tan (x-x)}{\sin (x-x)} = \frac{\sin (x-x)}{\cos (x-x)}.\frac1{\sin(x-x)}$ You are correct till here, but you can not cancel out $\sin(x-x)$ to get $\frac1{\cos (x-x)}$. You might have done cancelling "like that" in other limit problems but not actually this. The thing is that any term $y$ in $y\over  y$ can be cancelled if and only if $y\neq 0$. 
As such, $y$ can be cancelled and ${y\over  y}=1$ when $y \to 0$ because $y$ never reaches 0, it can only become close to it. $y \to 0 \implies y \in (0-\epsilon, 0+ \epsilon)\setminus \{0\}$ where $\epsilon \in \Bbb R$ is arbitrary

Comment: But in your case $y=\sin (x-x)=0$ no matter what domain you choose restricting  $x$ to any interval.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you sure those parentheses were there? Maybe it was a typo. Observe that
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x-x}{\sin x-x}=-2$$
which was one of the choices. Without those silly parentheses,
$$\sin x-x=(\sin x)-x=-\frac16x^3+\frac1{120}x^5-\cdots$$
and
$$\tan x-x=(\tan x)-x=\frac13x^3+\frac2{15}x^5+\cdots.$$

The limit of the quotient can be seen immediately from the Maclaurin series. Somewhat more tediously, we can apply l'Hospital's rule twice:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x-x}{\sin x-x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sec^2x-1}{\cos x-1}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2\sec^2x\tan x}{-\sin x}=\lim_{x\to0}-2\sec^3x=-2.$$

Comment: This is also accessible by repeated application of LHR, so this is likely the intended exercise given what OP is learning now.

Comment: Why are you using the MacLaurin series expansions of both functions in your evaluation of the limit?? That seems unnecessarily tedious.

Comment: @ArjunVyavaharkar: what on earth do you mean? It is the simplest way to evaluate the limit, as far as I can see.

Comment: Not really, especially since it only works within a certain radius of convergence. This example involves two nice functions (both of which have an ROC of infinity), but other functions are not so nice. Hell, most don't even have Taylor series expansions, so that's a bust. The simplest way to evaluate a limit is simply by plugging in the number x (or whatever variable you're using) is approaching, and if not, you could just use L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: @ArjunVyavaharkar (1) Since the problem asks for the limit at $0$, any positive radius of convergence suffices. (2) The radius of convergence of the tangent series is $\frac{\pi}2$ not $\infty$. (3) Hell, most functions are nondifferentiable, so L'Hospital's rule is out. (4) But what the hell do properties of "most functions" have to do with solving this particular calculus problem about the limit of the quotient of two very nice functions?

Comment: My mistake; I should have said that the ROC for $\sin(x)-x$ is infinite and the ROC for $\tan(x)-x$ is nicely within the vertical asymptotes on either side of it. However, my point still remains in that using the MacLaurin series expansions of any two functions to evaluate their limit is already very tedious. And you're demonstrably incorrect when saying that using series expansions to evaluate this one particular limit would be less tedious than LHR because it literally requires you to differentiate both the numerator and the denominator thrice, not just twice, and evaluate them at $0$.

Comment: @ArjunVyavaharkar There is nothing at all tedious about **using** the Maclaurin series to evaluate the limit. I think what you're trying to say is that **finding** the Maclaurin series is tedious. That's only a consideration if one does not already know the Maclaurin series. I think everybody knows the Maclaurin series for $\sin x$ and $\cos x$. I will admit that I didn't remember the tangent series but I calculated the first few terms very quickly without any differentiation, just divided the sine series by the cosine series.

Comment: Perhaps; I guess it depends on how you define 'easy.' Using the MacLaurin series to evaluate the limit is still somewhat tedious because you must differentiate the first terms of both series three times in order to get a constant value, after which all subsequent terms go to $0$. You must also justify the case for using both expansions. But is it not more elegant to use the properties of trigonometric functions to evaluate a limit involving them than to just use a series? It's kinda stupid, if you ask me.

Comment: No differentiation needed, just factor out $x^3$. $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac13x^3+\frac2{15}x^5+\cdots}{-\frac16x^3+\frac1{120}x^5-\cdots}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac13+\frac2{15}x^2+\cdots}{-\frac16+\frac1{120}x^2-\cdots}=\frac{\frac13}{-\frac16}=-2.$$ "It's kinda stupid, if you ask me." Remind me not to ask you.

Comment: @ArjunVyavaharkar Among the important "prop;erties of trigonometric functions" are their series expansions.

Comment: Alright, you've made your point.  I'll be completely honest in that I tried factoring out the $x^3$ term but then gave up when I realized that LHR wasn't gonna give a clean answer with constant terms on both the top and the bottom (without realizing that I could've just cancelled the two $x^3$ factors out). Oops :P

Answer (score 6):

They expect you to divide out the $\sin(x-x)$, get $\frac 1{\cos (x-x)}$ and say the limit is $1$.  They are lazily making use of the fact that we can cancel terms that look like $0$ in limits because we do not evaluate them when $x$ is at the limit.

They are missing the fact that you substitute the same value of $x$ everywhere it appears in the expression.  When you do that, you get $\frac 00$ uniformly, regardless of the value of $x$.  Even when $x \neq 0$ you cannot calculate the value of the expression.  I agree with you that the answer should be undefined.

Comment: I would say the answer should be "[Mu!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative)?wprov=sfti1)", indicating the premise of the question is invalid.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin:  Many of the multiple choice tests I took over the years asked for the best answer, which I always thought was saying they didn't want to spend the effort to make sure any answer was really right.  That is better than any that were presented.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Nu! The answer is Nooo...

Comment: Thanks @RossMillikan, so is the best choice in this case 1 or 0?.. I picked 1 and got it wrong..! so it must be 0..? What assumption do we have to make to get to 0..?

Comment: I don't see any way to get $0$.  I stated my case for $1$ and do not see any case for any of the others you are given.  I think @ArturoMagidin has the right idea, especially if $1$ is wrong.

Comment: I'm guessing it was a typo and the question was supposed to be $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x-x}{\sin x-x}$$ in which case $-2$ would be the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

As noticed the given expression for the limit is meaningless.

Another possible typo could be for:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} \frac{\tan (x - x_0)}{\sin (x-x_0)}=1$$

which is one of the option.